# Calculating numbers of 0 and 1 for different combinations of columns

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say that I have  matrix with (r1,...rm) rows and (c1,c2,...cn) all elements are 0's and 1's.

I'd like to count total number of 0s and 1s for different combinations: e.g., c1&c2, !c1&c3, c1&c3, c1&c2&c3, c1&c3&c4.

Is there an efficient way to count these?

I do it poorly like this, where data is my matrix.

```
is.one <- function(data,zero.one)
{ 
        #zero.one is logical , T, counting 1, otherwise 0s.

        if (zero.one)
            return (data==1)
        else
            return (data==0)
}

sum.one <- function(data, comb, zero.one)
{
        #comb is one of the combinations as a vector
        index<- rep(T,nrow(data))

        for (i in 1: length(comb))
        {
            # assuming i-th column is the i-th element of combination
            index <- is.one(data[,i], zero.one[i])
            data <- data[index,] 
        }

        return(sum(index))
}
```

Examples:

```
sum.one (data, c("c1","c2"), c(1,1))

sum.one (data, c("c1","c2","c3"), c(1,1,1))

sum.one (data, c("c1","c2","c3"), c(1,1,0))
```

I'd rather not calculating c1, or c2 for every combinations they appear, and keeping index could be a memory issue when m (nrow(data)) is big.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to convert the matrix into a dataframe using `reshape2`

```
df <- as.data.frame(your_matrix)
```

Then you can easily sum up the columns and save them in another variable

```
df <- data.frame(
  c1 = sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),
  c2 = sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),
  c3 = sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),
  c4 = sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 100)
)

  ones <- as.numeric(colSums(df))
  zeros <- as.numeric(NROW(df) - ones)


> ones
c1 c2 c3 c4 
39 45 41 50

> zeros
c1 c2 c3 c4 
61 55 59 50
```

you could then use these vectors for your combinations. For example: how many ones are in column 2 and how many 0s are in column 4?

```
> answer <- as.numeric(ones[2] + zeros[4])
> answer
[1] 95
```

Comment: Any reason for importing `reshape2`?

Comment: That works, but I think my functions work as well, but not memory efficient. If I want to know c1& !c4 & c5, then I need to calculate it from scratch, however you know which rows are c1&!c4 from above.

Comment: sorry, the reshape2 - import was not necessary. I've removed it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), 3, 3)
rownames(data) <- paste0("r", 1:nrow(data))
colnames(data) <- paste0("c", 1:ncol(data))
data
#    c1 c2 c3
# r1  1  0  1
# r2  0  0  0
# r3  0  0  1
```

You could create multi dimensional object containing all of the results and then select the values you need:

```
x <- colSums(data)
y <- colSums(data==0)
names(y) <- paste0(names(y), "_0")
o1 <- outer(x, y, FUN = "+")
o1
#    c1_0 c2_0 c3_0
# c1    3    4    2
# c2    2    3    1
# c3    4    5    3

o2 <- outer(o1, y, FUN = "+")
o2
# , , c1_0
# 
# c1_0 c2_0 c3_0
# c1    5    6    4
# c2    4    5    3
# c3    6    7    5
# 
# , , c2_0
# 
# c1_0 c2_0 c3_0
# c1    6    7    5
# c2    5    6    4
# c3    7    8    6
# 
# , , c3_0
# 
# c1_0 c2_0 c3_0
# c1    4    5    3
# c2    3    4    2
# c3    5    6    4

o2[1, 1, 2]
# [1] 6
```

Comment: Thanks, but this for a big matrix for is not practical, when n & m are greater than 100000.

Comment: In your example: c1&c2=0, c1&c3=1, !c1&!c2=2. Your response doesn't give me what I want. I want to have a function that keeps the previous calculation, so it doesn't do it every single time.